# Basic concepts and terminology about polyhedra

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra

Currently I am reading the book Convex Polyhedra, of A.D Alexandrov,  2005, in order to understand the uniqueness theorem (s) posted mainly in chapter 3. But I am really struggling with definitions given,  like development,  gluing,  complete angle of a development at an interior point,  net,  etc. These things I think,  are basic in discrete geometry but the way they are presented gives me  a hard time to understand in a strict mathematical way those things.  I wonder if there is a sourse where I can find these elementary definitions. Thanks in advance.